# JSP ajaxComplete callback

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, callback

we are facing issues with ajaxComplete() callback and I thought I'd ask for help here

Following is the snippet of code

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings) {
if (xhr && xhr.status == 0 && xhr.readyState == 0
{
   $.unblockUI();
   jAlert('Unable to contact the server', 'Connection Timeout');
```

}
            });

This condition occurs intermittently in our PROD environment and the client is annoyed by the popup with the connection time out message. As they are able to proceed further after clicking Ok button of the alert. Basically, they don't want to see the above message, instead they want the code to retry the request and continue the flow once the readyState==4.

Could anyone tell me, how to call this callback (ajaxComplete() again after may be 1 sec delay?  would settimeout() work in this case?  If so, could anyone give me a snippet of code to show how it is done.  I am new to front end coding and I'd really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Since you're using jquery's `$()` already why not also use jquery's `$.ajax()`?

Comment: @developerwjk -   Could you please elaborate?

Comment: why do you have that block of code in first place?

Comment: I'd use `$.ajax()` with `success` and `error` functions defined.

Comment: I will try .ajax() - Thank you @developerwjk.

Comment: @guilhebl -  Somebody else coded the functionality and they are no longer with the company, so we have no clue why they went with that approach,  but I ended up troubleshooting/ fixing the bug :).